# Child access parent component

Tags: reactjs

Any ideas if there's a clean solution for this "paradoxon"?

```
class Container extends Component {
    render() {
        <Parent> // ---------v
            <Child parent={Parent} /> // Reference to "Parent"
        </Parent>
    }
}
```

The problem is, of course, that `<Child>` is rendered *before* `<Parent>`.

Ultimately, the goal is to be able to call instance methods of `<Parent>` from within `<Child>`.

I have already tried workarounds such as `(ref)`, callback functions (`getParentReference()`), passing the reference by adding it as a new prop using `cloneElement()` or even `this._reactInternalInstance`, but none of them seemed to work (apart from being extremely hacky).

Comment: you can pass method as parameter. for example `<Child parentMethod={this.yourMethod}/>`

Comment: If you really want to do it, pass necessary method as prop into child.

Comment: @Abhishek, @dfsq: The method is _within_ `<Parent>`...

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use callback functions.

## Callback Functions

The parent would pass a function to the child as a prop, like this:

```
<MyChild myFunc={this.handleChildFunc.bind(this)} />
```

And the child would call that function like so:

```
this.props.myFunc();
```

And don't forget that the child will need this function declared in its propTypes:

```
MyChild.propTypes = {
  myFunc: React.PropTypes.func,
};
```

For more information, read [8 no-Flux strategies for React component communication](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/#3-callback-functions)

Comment: Thanks, but the function that I want to pass sits _within_ `<Parent>`. There is no _this.handleChildFunc()_...

Comment: Just define the `handleChildFunc` in the `Parent` component and then pass it as prop to the `MyChild` component like in the example. Seems like you misunderstood the concept. :)

Comment: I've updated my code snippet to illustrate my problem better. Please note that I'm not trying to add a prop from `Container` (which the example you provided does) but from my `<Parent>` component (which is _not_ `<Container>`).